# How to make an existing wxPython code run on Mac with conda?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I have an existing wxPython code which runs perfectly on linux and which i want to run on mac. I have the installation through anaconda on both linux and mac.

For mac, i am getting the error "**This program needs access to the screen.Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac**."

I installed pythonw on through anaconda and I am able to run wx.APP() when running python through the location "**/Users/vnigam200/anaconda/bin/pythonw**".

I am not sure how to use this location for running my existing script. I tried shebang but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Macs you need to run `pythonw` for wxPython scripts instead of the default, which is `python`. This is a known problem with Anaconda that they don't seem willing to fix:

- https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/anaconda/osx$20framework/anaconda/1rX3A1Noi9Q/68MNJWLxupYJ

So basically just do the following in Mac's terminal:

```
pythonw /path/to/your/script.py
```

Then it should work fine.

Comment: Your first link does not work